# How do you open a specific folder in Finder without applescript?

Tags: terminal, finder, bash

#### Background

I've replaced Finder as the default folder-opening app by editing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`:

```
<snip>
{
    LSHandlerContentType = "public.folder";
    LSHandlerPreferredVersions = {
        LSHandlerRoleAll = "-";
    };
    LSHandlerRoleAll = "org.yanex.marta";
},
<snip>
```

So now when I type `open .` or similar in the terminal, it opens the directory in Marta instead. That's good, I want that.

#### Issue

There's only one exception where I want to use Finder, and that's when opening the `/Applications` folder, since Marta is unable to delete stuff from /Applications.

I know this can be done with applescript, but applescripts have a few seconds' delay before they run, which I'm hoping to eliminate by using bash instead.

The purpose of all this is to have a script which can be called from [raycast](https://raycast.com/).

So far I've tried:

```bsh
/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app /Applications # requires sudo

open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app --args /Applications # just opens Finder but doesn't open the folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing in both **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur**, the following *command* in **Terminal** opens a **Finder** *window* to **/Applications**:

```
open -a Finder /Applications
```